# Kendo Dropdownlist: Grouping data causes undefined

Tags: kendo-ui

Im trying to use an existing data file to populate a kendo drop down list.The field im interested in populating my drop down list is the "make" field which basically displays a list or car manufacturers.

this works fine...

```
var makes = $("#makes").kendoDropDownList({
        optionLabel: "Select make...",
        dataTextField: "make",
        dataValueField: "make",
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    url: "data.php",
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: "data"
            }
        }
    }).data("kendoDropDownList");
```

However there are many makes repeated as its a list of car specs so i want to be able to group the data by make to hide the repetitions. As soon as i add this line the dropdowlist options become undefined.

```
 group: { field: "make" }
```

Code after i added group

```
 var makes = $("#makes").kendoDropDownList({
        optionLabel: "Select make...",
        dataTextField: "make",
        dataValueField: "make",
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    url: "data.php",
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: "data"
            },
            group: { field: "make" }
        }
    }).data("kendoDropDownList");
```

Any idea's guys

thanks

UPDATE!!

Using this below i can now group the data but the cascading isnt working

```
var data = [
  {"make": "Audi", "model": "A1"},
  {"make": "Audi", "model": "A2"},
  {"make": "Audi", "model": "A3"},
  {"make": "Audi", "model": "A4"},
  {"make": "Saab", "model": "S500"}
];

$(document).ready(function () {

  var makesDatasource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
      data: data,
      group: { field: "make", value: "make"}
  });

  var makes = $("#makes").kendoDropDownList({
        optionLabel: "Select make...",
        dataTextField: "value",
        dataValueField: "value",
        dataSource: makesDatasource
  }).data("kendoDropDownList");

  var modelsDatasource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
      data: data,
      group: { field: "model", value: "model"}
  });

  var models = $("#models").kendoDropDownList({
        autoBind: false,
        cascadeFrom: "makes",
        optionLabel: "Select model...",
        dataTextField: "value",
        dataValueField: "value",
        dataSource: modelsDatasource
  }).data("kendoDropDownList");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Grouped data looks like:

```
[
  { field: "make", value: "Make 1", items: [...]},
  ...
]
```

so try changing to:

```
    dataTextField: "value",
    dataValueField: "value",
```

Comment: thanks. if i group the data like you suguest however i cant get the cascading dropdownlist to work. ive amended the code above to include your suggestion

Comment: if I have a list of items that I want to group by one of their properties, I setup a grouping like group: { field: "make" } on the datasource. on databound i inspect the datasource which is jsut a flat list of items/objects that have a Make property. the datasource.view however knows that the data needs to be grouped like you say { field="make", value= "Mazda", items=[10]}, so your dataTextField=value suggestion is good, the groups render properly but they don't render as option groupings and their child items don't get rendered..... so the kendo drop down doesn't support option groupings doh